# Extending Perl Regex to account for more characters?

Tags: regex, perl

So I have this regex to match any email address, and I need to extend it to include the following,

> : or ; after the email, followed by 14 characters of any possible type.

This is my expression as it is now:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}
```

And I have no idea how to approach this, can anyone help?

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}+{:;}+{14*}
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: With `[...]`, you may form a character class. Not with `{...}`. With `{number}`, you may specify the exact number of the left-hand pattern repetition. Try `[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}[:;].{14}`. Maybe add anchors if you need to match the whole string. It would be better if you provided some more code where you use the regex pattern.

Comment: Oh so uh [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}+[:;]+[14*] ?

Comment: Your regex excludes many valid email addresses. You should use something like [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid) instead.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot For my purposes it matches what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b(?:[;:][\s\S]{0,14})?
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/TGS1md/1)

Be aware that *14 characters of any possible type* is quite ambiguous. Does that include `\0` or `\n`? The construct of `[\s\S]` matches 'any possible character' so clarify if you mean something different.

Comment: It means any normal character, text wise such as A-Za-z, symbols, numbers essentially

Comment: @Link: What about spaces?